# Defining a smooth line on a image with disjointed boundary

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Consider this image:

[image]

After doing `I = edge(I, 'log', [])` on an image, I obtained this segmentation. Now, inside the red circles, if you notice, the lines are disjointed. How exactly would I just close these lines without affecting other parts of the image? I tried `fill` operations and detect boundary operations. But none of them simply did I what I want to. They either colored in other parts of the image and disregarded the disjointed structures altogether.

How do I get around this?

Comment: You can use `[BW,threshOut] = edge(I,'log')` to get the threshold(threshOut) and then change the value a little bit and use it in the function. Like this: `BW = edge(I,'log',threshold)`

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to segment objects but you are segmenting their boundaries instead. It is typically a bad idea to try to find objects using an edge detector. They are unlikely to produce complete boundaries, and then you have the problem that you're having now. You need to directly segment the objects themselves. Thresholding, watershed, level sets, graph cuts, even snakes, they all segment objects. -- Note that the other question you posted, about segmenting individual blobs, is caused by the same wrong approach.